# Different Behaviour of TRIM in php

Tags: php

I have a piece of code, from this i want to remove some words from string but the `trim()` function is not showing proper output.

The code is below

```
<?php
$mystring = '/word-quotes-hope';
$findme   = '/word-quotes-';
echo $str = trim($mystring, $findme);
?>
```

and its output is `hop`, but it should be `hope`

Its working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/FxLZkp

Anybody knows why this is happening.

Comment: Just like complex857 said, trim() function uses all of the characters in the string of the second parameter to truncate the ends of the first. You'll want to use str_replace() to do string replacement. Also consider looking at preg_replace() and use regex to search for left side or right side replacements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `trim` uses the second string individual characters, not the whole string, and in your case it has an `e` in it, and the string ends with `e` so off it goes.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka `o` is not trimmed because it's in the middle of the word `hope` not at the end of either side.

Comment: Its not affected because the `p` after it doesn't in the `$findme`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it with "ltrim"

```
echo $str = ltrim($mystring, $findme);
```

it will trims your string on "left"